# Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch--not work on every PC?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I use localhost for redirect_uri.
(Of course I registered in the APIs console)
And I tried the application on 6 PCs(from different guys).

There are 3 PCs can succeed redirecting url to the google account login page.
But the others can NOT work,and show redirect_uri_mismatch.(Showed different port each time.ex:127.0.0.1:49328 127.0.0.1:49254...)

Why it can NOT work fine on every PC?

Comment: Are they all on the same network and also it's hard to figure out what is going wrong so can you add details?

Comment: I used the same wireless network.
And what  details can I add?